# powerbuilder - change column order of a datawindow at runtime

Tags: powerbuilder

I have a datawindow (in grid-style) with some columns. It is possible to change the column order with drag'n drop in runtime.

Can I rearrange the column order by code (for example in a buttonclicked event) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To move the columns dynamically in execution and with the mouse you have to have active in the datawindow the property "Column Moving". You can also do it by code, it is advisable a window to the user to indicate the order and accordingly encode the creation of a datawindow dynamically and then assign it to the dataobject to do the retrieve.

Comment: It was easy with `dwo.Modify( ls_controlname + 'X=' + ls_newposition`.  The challange was to find the `ls_newposition` for every control.